# ext js reference in controller how to configure

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have ViewController and View (Panel with reference: "table1")
I want to configure listeners on it inside my ViewController:

```
    control: {
            '#table1': {
                click: 'clickButton'
            },                
        },
...
```

but '#table1' works only with itemId and Id but not with references. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this the way mentioned by Pawel or if you really need to use the control object:

```
control: {
    '[reference=table1]': {
        click: 'clickButton'
    },                
},
```

Comment: This is what I want! Thank you

Comment: This may not be want you want in MVVC. In MVC you want this, in MVVC you want to configure a function on the handler config of the button in the view..

Comment: It depends, I still like to use this.control({}) in MVVM so I can keep all my methods and listeners in one place.

Answer (score 1):

This is example how it works with references:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.foo.Foo', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'foo',
    controller: 'foo',

    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Add',
        handler: 'onAdd'
    }],

    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        reference: 'fooGrid'
        ...
    }]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.foo.FooController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.foo',

    onAdd: function () {
        var grid = this.lookupReference('fooGrid');
    }
});
```

For more information please read: [ViewControllers - how do they works ?](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/application_architecture/view_controllers.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer for MVVC! The author of the OP is confusing MVC with MVVC and he answer of Guilherme Lopes is not correct..